# Why are only some of my CSS selectors working?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm a bit new to HTML/CSS and I'm having a really hard time figuring out why some of my selectors aren't working.

As with it stands right now, only the .tasklist and .totalleft seem to be in effect. I've tried changing them all to class selectors but that doesn't seem to work either. I think the syntax is correct, as I've tried only doing one at a time and they work, but it's when they are all together that it doesn't work. What I am missing here...? Thanks!

HTML

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="demoController">

    <center><h1>Todos by Angular.js</h1></center>

    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="input" placeholder="What needs to be done?">
      <button type="submit" ng-click="add()">Add task</button>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allChecked" ng-change="markAll(allChecked)">Mark all as complete<br>

    <ul class="tasklist" >
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.done">
        <label id="done-{{item.done}}">{{item.val}}</label>
        <hr>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br>

    <div class="totalleft">
      {{numLeft()}} out of {{items.length}} remaining
      <button id="clearbutton" type="submit" ng-click="clearItems()" ng-show="showClear()">Clear {{numCompleted()}} items</button>
    </div>

  </body>
```

CSS

```
.tasklist {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-indent: 0px;
}​

#done-true {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: grey;
}

.totalleft {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  color: dark grey;
}​

#clearbutton{
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

Comment: what result are you getting and what result do you expect? I cant see the `#done-true` in your html.

Comment: @Dejan.S the done true is in `<label id="done-{{item.done}}">{{item.val}}</label>`

Comment: @Dejan.S this is a dynamic id created with `<label id="done-{{item.done}}">{{item.val}}</label>`

Comment: ah got it now, at quick glans did not notice it. Can you verify that the value `item.done` is true? also what does your button look like with 50%?

Comment: Your CSS is correct, they must be getting overridden by other styles from your stylesheet or possible inline styles when the final code is compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you copied that code straight from your text editor? When I copy/paste it into the SO editor I am seeing an extra UTF character:

[image: code showing red dots extra character]

See the red dots? When I remove them in the editor the styling works. Here is your code without the extra elements:

```
.tasklist {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

#done-true {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: grey;
}

.totalleft {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  color: dark grey;
}

#clearbutton{
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

```css
.tasklist {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

#done-true {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: grey;
}

.totalleft {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  color: dark grey;
}

#clearbutton{
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="demoController">

    <center><h1>Todos by Angular.js</h1></center>

    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="input" placeholder="What needs to be done?">
      <button type="submit" ng-click="add()">Add task</button>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allChecked" ng-change="markAll(allChecked)">Mark all as complete<br>

    <ul class="tasklist" >
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.done">
        <label id="done-{{item.done}}">{{item.val}}</label>
        <hr>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br>

    <div class="totalleft">
      {{numLeft()}} out of {{items.length}} remaining
      <button id="clearbutton" type="submit" ng-click="clearItems()" ng-show="showClear()">Clear {{numCompleted()}} items</button>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Goddamn that was it. I guess CSS is really specific about it's spacing then. Thanks!!

Comment: It was not a spacing issue. It was a hidden text character after the closing bracket that was causing the issue.

Comment: Huh. I tried copying your edited code and it worked fine. But to double check, I tried copying the code in the op and re-edited it. I'm not doing anything besides enter for a new line, but the problem persists. Could it be a problem with the editor...? I'm currently using notepad++

Comment: So I did a showall of characters, turns out there was indeed a hidden character.

Comment: It was like a invisible layered curlybrace. How could that have possibly happened I wonder...?

Comment: I don't know what may have caused this.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King nice catch